# Android String size in pixels

Tags: android, string, canvas

I'm trying to draw a String on Canvas. I need to have the String centered horizontally on the screen and the String is dynamic as it grows as you add more chars to it(up to 7 chars). How is it possible to get the length of the String in pixels so I can do some calculations to have it centered?

Answer (score 0):

For text use **sp** rather than pixels and center your textview from its xml file.

android:gravity="center"

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a StaticLayout for this. If you set the width to the size of the canvas and alignment to center then you shouldn't need to do any calculations yourself.

Call this function whenever the text changes and in the View's onSizedChanged function:

```
StaticLayout sl;

private void initText(){

    TextPaint paint = new TextPaint();
    paint.setTextSize(16);
    paint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);

    sl = new StaticLayout("My String", paint, myCanvasWidth,   Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1F, 0F, false);
}
```

And then in onDraw:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
   sl.draw(canvas);
}
```

If you need to position the text vertically, use something like this:

```
int save = canvas.save();
canvas.translate(0, yOffset);
sl.draw(canvas);
canvas.restoreToCount(save);
```

And if you really need to know the width of the text then:

```
sl.getWidth();
```

Answer (score -1):

Android has the method

```
public float measureText (String text)
```

Added in API level 1
Return      the width of the text.
Parameters  textThe text to measure. Cannot be null.
Returns     * The width of the text

So the answer:

```
float textPixelWidth = paintText.measureText(strText);
```